# Updating object properties in twig

Tags: php, twig

Is there a way to update an object's property in twig?

An object like the following is passed to twig:

```
object
   property1
   property2
```

I would like to update property1 like this:

```
{% set object.property1 = 'somenewvalue' %}
```

*The above code does not work*, but is it possible to do something like this in twig? If not, is there a way to write an extension or macro to do this?

Comment: Please ignore my answer below, it is very out of date and should no longer be the accepted answer. Unfortunately I can't delete it as it is the accepted answer.

Comment: @rdjs Thanks for letting me know! I have swapped the accepted answer!

Comment: The accepted answer only works for arrays and hashes, not objects.

Comment: I created an issue about this: https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/2768

Comment: According to symfony crew trying to do this is "busines logic in twig", which should be avoided. See https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/2768#issuecomment-442368654

Answer (score 75, accepted):

**Answer from 2013**

You can do it by merging objects:

```
{% set object = object|merge({'property1': 'somenewvalue'}) %}
```

**Update from 2023**

I don’t know from which version of twig this solution does not work anymore. Now you can only create an object with a new name:

```
{% set data = {foo:1} %}
{% set updated = data|merge({ bar: 2 }) %}

foo: {{ updated.foo }} {# Produces “foo: 1” #}
bar: {{ updated.bar }} {# Produces “bar: 2” #}
```

Comment: +1 great native way to do this. Perfect for single usage scenario.

Comment: So, why is this the accepted answer? Is this working only under some Twig versions?

Comment: It shouldn't be the accepted answer since it does not respond to the question which is 'how to update properties from an object'.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer indeed - as per Twig error output: 

The merge filter only works with arrays or "Traversable", got "object" as first argument.

@Baishu's answer below works for my Object use-case

Comment: It works for arrays not objects, I'm afraid. This is a misleading answer.

Comment: The 2013 answer has always been working for my objects, with Twig 3.5.0 (and previous versions)
{% set o = {a: 1} %}
{% set o = o|merge({a: 2}) %}
This works like a charm

Answer (score 11):

Twig has a [do](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/do.html) tag that allows you to do that.

```
{% do foo.setBar(value) %}
```

Comment: Might work for method calls, but does not work in the scenario described by OP: Unexpected token "operator" of value "="

Comment: Indeed, it only works if the method exists.

Answer (score 4):

A possible way to set a property is to create a method in the object which actually creates new properties:

```
class Get extends StdClass 
  {

    protected function setProperty($name,$value = null)
    {
    $this->$name = $value;
    }

  }
```

Comment: I had to set this method public, but it is indeed a nice solution

Comment: What? And how in the world do you call that from Twig?

Comment: @BrunoSantos `object.setProperty("propertyName", 3)` this will set/create `propertyName` to `3`

Comment: in twig: ``{% do object.setProperty("propertyName", 3) %}``

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in my knp menu template. I wanted to render an alternate field with the `label` block, without duplicating it. Of course the underlying object needs an setter for the property.

```
{%- block nav_label -%}
    {%- set oldLabel = item.label %}
    {%- set navLabel = item.getExtra('nav_label')|default(oldLabel) %}
    {{- item.setLabel(navLabel) ? '' : '' }}
    {{- block('label') -}}
    {{- item.setLabel(oldLabel) ? '' : '' }}
{%- endblock -%}
```

Comment: instead of ``{{- xx.f() ? '' : '' }}``, use this: ``{% do xx.f()  %}``, it never prints anything. https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/do.html

Answer (score 1):

If your property is array (object->property['key']) you can do something like this:

```
{% set arr = object.property|merge({"key":['some value']}) %}
{{ set(object, 'property', arr) }}
```

That equivalent to:

```
this->property['key'][] = 'some value';
```

Comment: You saved my time :)

Comment: again, only yii2

Answer (score -6):

```
{{ set(object, 'property', value) }}
```