# Adding a property to an object in twig

Tags: php, twig

I want to add property 2 to this object in twig

```
object
    property1
```

According to this question [Updating object properties in twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719838/updating-object-properties-in-twig) The accepted answer says that it can be achieved by merge, but merge filter does not work with objects, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: How about writing custom twig function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most elegant way is using setters and getters:

```
class TestStdClass
{
    private $prop1;

    public function getProp1()
    {
        return $this->prop1;
    }

    public function setProp1($prop1)
    {
        $this->prop1 = $prop1;
    }
}
```

Then in a Twig template use tag [`do`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/do.html) to evaluate expression (`obj` is an instance of `TestStdClass`):

```
{{ dump(obj) }} {# will print an empty object #}
{% do obj.setProp1('Hello') %}
{{ dump(obj) }}
```

This will print:

```
TestStdClass {#2468 ▼
  -prop1: "Hello"
}
```

Comment: In this way you need to add getters and setters in each class for each property. Ofcourse if we will write code like this it will be more clear but this is not a universal way to append new property to objects. My solution can add properties dinamically without getters and setters.

Answer (score 2):

Don`t know about standart way to do it in twig, but i think that you can do it like this:

**1. Create custum twig extension**

```
class TwigPropertySetter extends \Twig_Extension {

    function getName() {
        return 'property_setter';
    }

    function getFunctions() {
        return [
            'setObjectProperty' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'setObjectProperty')
        ];
    }

    function setObjectProperty($object, $propertyName, $propertyValue) {
        $object->{$propertyName} = $propertyValue;
        return $object;            
    }    
}
```

**2. Add extension to your twig renderer**

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment(null, $options);
$twig->addExtension(new TwigPropertySetter());
```

**3. Use function in your twig template**

```
....
{% set object = setObjectProperty(object, 'property2', 'value2') %}
Show new object porperty {{ object.property2 }}
....
```

***Notice: Not tested***

Comment: `getName` is a required function when extending from `Twig_Extension`

Answer (score 1):

You could also add a general setter to your class to get the dynamicity like in Kison's solution:

```
class Foo {
    public function setProperty($name, $value) {
        $this->$name = $value;
    }
}
```

And then in Twig:

```
{% do obj.setProperty('property2', 'Second property') %}
```

This is simpler than Kison's solution and more dynamic than martin's solution. However, if you have many classes that need this kind of general setter, then Kison's solution might be better as it's more universal (i.e. you can add properties to objects of any class).