# Update object property value

Tags: twig

How to update the object property value

```
{set shopping.totalValue = shopping.totalValue + 0.10}
```

I'm getting an error. Please help.

Comment: change it in PHP FIRST. Stop putting putting business logic in your view files!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a property to an object in twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38968967/adding-a-property-to-an-object-in-twig)