# Update object attributes in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I already check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719838/updating-object-properties-in-twig)

I have a similar problem

I have a variable object with attributes others objects

so I Have the main object and I want put null to one of their properties

I tried this options but they fail of course, before each line I put the error that give me

```
set object.other = null
--------------------------------------
Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "." ("end of statement block" expected) 

set object["other"] = null
--------------------------------------
Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "[" ("end of statement block" expected)

set (object, 'other', null)
--------------------------------------
Only variables can be assigned to. Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "(" ("name" expected) 

set object = object|merge({'other',null})
--------------------------------------
The merge filter only works with arrays or "Traversable", got "object" as first argument
```

Please Help

Comment: can you bake a pie in a freezer? No. Why? Because freezers are not designed to bake a pie! Twig is made to render a view. not to build objects. That is what you should do in the controller or any service

Comment: Is object initializated before any other assignment ?

Comment: Can you show your full code, and in particular what is `object`? You could also `dump(object)` it to show what it looks like.

Comment: I need overwrite  the object to simulate an error, so if you don't add something useful please abstain

Answer (score 1):

The first three of your examples are not valid Twig syntax, like the error messages say.

The fourth example, using Twig's merge filter, would work if your object was an array, a hash (i.e. `{% set object = { other: 'something' } %}`), or an instance of a Traversable class. Your object is none of these, as can be seen from the error message returned by Twig: *'The merge filter only works with arrays or "Traversable", got "object" as first argument.'* Note also that you have a typo (as already mentioned by aferber): you have `{'other', null}` whereas you should have `{'other': null}` (or `{other: null}`).

Thus, what you are trying to do can't be done out-of-the-box in Twig. You need to either modify your class (e.g. create a method which sets the `other` property to null) or create a Twig extension. The question [Adding a property to an object in twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38968967/adding-a-property-to-an-object-in-twig/48176236) has answers showing how you could approach these solutions.

A third possibility would be to modify your class so that the object is Traversable. Then you could use the merge filter.

Of course one more possibility is to stop trying to do this in Twig and do this e.g. in a controller (as already suggested by Frank B).

Answer (score -1):

In order for this to work, `object` has to be an object in the first place. The error message to your last try (merge filter) clearly shows this isn't the case (in PHP, every object is Traversable). In addition, the object has to have a *public* property named `other`.

You should also pay attention to the difference between `{'other',null}` and `{'other': null}`.

After you have fixed all those problem (ie. made sure you assign an object to `object` first), the merge filter will work, just as it did in the question you linked to.

Comment: -1: First, if `object` was unassigned, Twig would say _'... got "NULL" as first argument,'_ so in OP's question `object` clearly is an object. Second, not every object is Traversable, [see the docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php). Third, no, Twig's merge filter will not work with non-Traversable objects, it only works with arrays or Traversible objects.